# Using SecKeyCreateRandomKey hangs main thread on some devices until reboot, how can I break the hang

Tags: multithreading, ios11, keychain

Main thread hang when trying the generate EC keys on Secure Enclave using SecKeyCreateRandomKey API.
Happened on two closely related customer devices, both iPhone7+, one 11.0.3, and another 11.1.
While debugging one device, same code without SE token ID keychain query attribute did not hang.
We used passcode requirement and device limit to the access control item.

Apple rejected our bug on terms of duplication. Any information about the original bug (33714117) or ways to recover are welcome.

Comment: I have the same issue on an iPhone 8 plus, iOS 11.1.2. I was stuck for an hour until reading your post, which led me to reboot the device... thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?